# What will be the automorphism group of the following graphs

Tags: graph-theory, automorphism-group

I am stuck on the following two questions on graph automorphisms?

My questions are the following :

1.How is $\def\Aut{\operatorname{Aut}} \Aut(G_1\cup G_2)$ related to $\Aut(G_1), \Aut(G_2)$?

2.How is $\Aut(G_1+ G_2)$ related to $\Aut(G_1), \Aut(G_2)$?

Here $G_1\cup G_2$ is the disjoint union of $G_1,G_2$ and $G_1+G_2$ is the join of $G_1,G_2$.

If someone can help, I will be grateful.

**My try**:

For the 1st question, since $G_1\cup G_2$ has two disjoint components so I guess
$\Aut(G_1\cup G_2)=\Aut(G_1)\times \Aut(G_2)$, where $\times$ denotes the direct product of two groups.

For the 2nd question,  $\Aut(G_1+ G_2)=\Aut(\overline{G_1+ G_2})=\Aut(\overline{G_1}\cup \overline{G_2})$

So if I can answer the 1st question, then the 2nd question will be answered.

Can someone please help me verify the 1st question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very brief hints.

If graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$ are connected and non-isomorphic, then indeed $$\operatorname{Aut}(G_1\cup G_2)\cong\operatorname{Aut}(G_1)\times \operatorname{Aut}(G_2).$$
If connected graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$ are isomorphic, then
$$\operatorname{Aut}(G_1\cup G_2)\cong(\operatorname{Aut}(G_1)\times \operatorname{Aut}(G_2))\rtimes C_2.$$
I think that if graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$ are disconnected, then there is no simple formula.